# How do I access a user-modified value that's embedded inside of a custom control?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How do I access a user-modified value that's embedded inside of a custom control?

I have a custom control:

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="MyNamspce.LabelValuePair"
    x:Name="ParentControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            ...
            <Entry Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ParentControl}, Path=ValueText}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Here's how I use the custom control:

```
<local:LabelValuePair
    ...
    ValueText="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PairTemplateToEntryConverter}}" />
```

Here's the backing data structure:

```
type LabelEntryPair2 () =

    member val LabelFGColor = "" with get,set
    member val Label        = "" with get,set
    member val EntryValue   = "" with get,set
    member val ValueFGColor = "" with get,set
```

I'm successful at loading values into the custom control.
However, I'm not able to retrieve the values after they are modified by the user.

**Note:**

The *ValueText* property's setter is triggered every time I edit the entry control value thru the user interface:

The value converter, *PairTemplateToEntryConverter*, never invokes the *ConvertBack* method after I edit the entry value.

```
public static BindableProperty ValueTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                    propertyName: "ValueText",
                    returnType: typeof(string),
                    declaringType: typeof(LabelValuePair),
                    defaultValue: "",
                    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string ValueText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueTextProperty, value); } // ** This is being triggered every time **
    }
```

However, I'm unable to pickup these updates on the actual data structure (i.e. *LabelEntryPair2*)

In conclusion, How do I access a user-modified value that's embedded inside of a custom control?

Comment: Your binding way in the contentview is weird. You can try to use  `propertyChanged` like this thread to get the user-modified value that's embedded inside of a custom control.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached

Comment: this is a good reference too https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/

Comment: Does the example in this video help - https://youtu.be/c_O7FDR5eIw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was this:

```
ValueText="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PairTemplateToEntryConverter}}"
```

So ValueText is being bound to the entire list item object, and then a converter is being used to extract the string from a string property on the object.This is an unusual approach and I see no real reason for it. Instead, why not just bind directly to the property on the object?> E.g:

```
ValueText="{Binding EntryValue}"
```